# How do I make navbar toggle button / drop-down-menu work in "sm" screen size using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, toggle, navbar

I am working on a website and I have spent a day or so trying to get the toggle button to display the drop down menu in "sm" screen size. If you click on the link below to my GitHub website you can see that the button appears and functions correctly when you minimize the screen size to "xs" (up to 767px), but does not function correctly in "sm" (768px to 991px).[Github website](https://lionunderatree.github.io/coursera/mod3_solution/index.html#)

*If you remove "visibility: hidden;" from the small @media querie you'll see that the dropdown is being displayed in the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that there are tons of `media-query` rules that are tangled together, making it hard to trace the problem's cause.

But I noticed that in your `styles.css` file, you have:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
...
#nav-list {
    visibility: hidden;
}
...
}
```

Which is the reason why the list is hidden in `sm` screens. However, even by removing this, there are still some styling that makes it behave differently (not aligned vertically) as wanted. I think you might want to consider cleaning the styling a bit, and get rid of any unwanted `media-queries`, and hopefully the problem's cause will show out right away.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If you remove "visibility: hidden;" in the browser editor, you'll see that the menu appears in a weird location. Not sure what I did wrong...but I'll keep trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your styleSheet that **left-margin = -25px**. Due to which whenever it come in that space it appears just besides the left border but increasing the width of screen it will be good.

I would suggest you to use **left-margin = 0px**. It will be good and act as like other sizes of screens.

```
---your code
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
/* Home Page */
.navbar-brand h1{
    font-size: 4vw;
    margin: 35px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

Use this one

```
  margin: 35px 0 0 0px;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However, your suggestion does not resolve correct the problem.